# Fetch in NextJS doesn't work. What should I do?

Tags: node.js, next.js, fetch-api

I try to use getStaticProps from NextJs for SSR, but there is always a problem with fetch. When I call fetch inside getStaticProps and try to render data it sends me a 505 Internal Server Error. While when I try to use useState and useEffect, fetch inside useEffect work correctly. I need to create SSR app, so I dont know what to do
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wXt8E.png)

```
const Users = ({ users }) => {
  return (
    <MainContainer keywords={"users next js"}>
      <h1>Cписок пользователей</h1>
      <ul>
        {users.map((user) => (
          <li key={user.id}>
            <Link href={`/users/${user.id}`}>
              <a>{user.name}</a>
            </Link>
          </li>
        ))}
      </ul>
    </MainContainer>
  );
};

export default Users;

export async function getStaticProps(context) {
  const response = await fetch(`https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users`);
  const users = await response.json();

  return {
    props: { users }, // will be passed to the page component as props
  };
}
```

Comment: Can you try switching to `getServerSideProps` and see if it's working ? Just want to compare. As per Next JS definition `getStaticProps` is for SSG but that shouldn't be a blocker in development.

Comment: Switched... Its all the same

Comment: Your code works fine for me (`next 12.1.5` and `react 18.0.0`) and all the user data renders correctly. Which versions of Next.js and React are you using? Does your `MainContainer` component also make any `fetch` calls?

Comment: I used the latest versions of react and next. No, there is no requests to server in MainContainer

Comment: You mentioned that the code works inside a `useEffect` hook, so I wonder if this might have something to do with how `fetch` behaves in Node.js (`getStaticProps`) compared to the browser (`useEffect`). Have you tried using something other than the native `fetch`, e.g., `axios`? Also, are you behind any type of proxy server?

Comment: I’ve updated the node and nodejs versions, tried to use axios but it doesnt work. Also when I deployed my project on free hosting it works correctly.